# R normalization with all samples, or just the part that i need?

Tags: r, dataframe, normalization, bioinformatics

I am using the edgeR and Limma packages to analyse a RNA-seq count data table.
I only need a subset of the data file, therefore my question is: Do I need to normalize my data within all the samples, or is it better to subset my data first and normalize the data then.

Thank you.

Regards Lisanne

Comment: Impossibly vague. And... Not a coding question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on what you want to proof/show. If you also want to take into account your "darkcounts" than you should normalize it at first such that you also take into account the percentage in which your experiment fails. Here your total number of experiments ( good and bad results) sums up to one.

If you want to find out the distribution of your "good events" than you should first produce your subset of good samples and normalize afterwards. In this case your number of good events sums up to 1

So once again, it depends on what you want to proof. As a physicist I would prefer the first method since we do not remove bad data points.

Cheers TL